# Fixing div at a specific position with negative margin, and animating it later on button click.

Tags: css, html, position

I have a somehow complicated situation:

Here is a fiddle to try and explain it: http://jsfiddle.net/sqSj9/1/

What I want to do is put three divs at a fixed positions, with a negative margin-left, top and right (so hidden) and as soon as I click on a button, they should appear in an animated way to the middle of the page. I started doing this in a separate folder to try it, and it was working perfectly. and I got the result that you can see in the fiddle, ( so yes the fiddle is what I want to accomplish)

But as soon as I put the code in my actual website's code, first nothing appeared on click, so the animation didn't work.

when I removed `position:fixed` the animation started to appear,but the divs that appeared pushed the div that is behind, so let's say in the fiddle: the white div pushed the gray div to the bottom, instead of hiding it.

So my last solution was to put `position:absolute` . when I did this, the animation worked correctly, but the thing is that now, when i click on the button, the divs are animated but do not fill the size of my browser, which means that, let's say I have scrolled down a bit more, when I click on the button to animate, the animation takes place but I don't see it. I have to scroll up again to see it.

Here is another fiddle to show what I mean. scroll down and try it: http://jsfiddle.net/6xJhC/3/

So I am sure the is something wrong with my initial code, something that I shouldn't have added, but I just can't figure out what it is! Here are relevant parts of my code:

My html:

```
 <?php include 'header.php';?>

    <!-- this is where the header ends and index starts-->
        <div id="container">
    <div id="intro">
       <!-- some content-->
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <section id="def">    
         <!-- some content-->
      </section>

      <div id="selected-program">
          <div id="top">  
              <!-- some content-->
          </div>

          <div id="left">
              <!-- some content-->
          </div>

          <div id="right">
              <!-- some content-->
          </div>
     </div>

     <section id="program">
        <button id="click" value="click Me"> click me </button>
        <!-- some content-->
     </section>

     <section id="rec">
        <!-- some content-->
     </section>

     <section id="testi">
        <!-- some content-->
     </section>

     <section id="contact">
         <!-- some content-->
     </section>


<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

My js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var allowScroll = true;

$("body").on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e){   // this code prevents scrolling whenever the button is clicked is clicked
    if (!allowScroll){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
$("#click").click(function(){
    $("#top").animate({marginTop:'0px'},200);
    $("#left").animate({marginLeft:'0px'},200);
    $("#right").animate({marginRight:'0px'},200);
});
});
</script>
```

My css:

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container{
    padding-top:80px;
}

#intro{
    background:url(images/main.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height:492px;
    color: #fff;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    width:100%;
}

#content{
    z-index: 600;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 492px;
    background: #fff;
}

#program {
    height:700px;
}

#rec{
    height:140px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}

#recommand{
    width:490px;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
}

#testi {
    height:700px;
}

section{
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    border-color:#eee;
    padding-left:130px;
}

#selected-program{
    z-index: 100000;
}

#top{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    margin-top:-120px;     
    background: #f6f6f6;
    position:absolute;
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
}

#left{
    left:0%;
    margin-left:-859px;
    padding-left:130px;
    padding-top:30px;
    width:860px;
    height:603px;
    margin-top:80px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
}

#right{
    right:0%;
    margin-right:-449px;
    float:right;
    height:633px;
    width:449px;
    margin-top:80px;
    border-left:1px solid #eee;
    position:absolute;
    background: #fff;
}
```

So Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read through that and it kinda made sense... but at the same time it didn't make sense (for me anyways). Could you create an image of what you want? Or explain it step by step. Also if its working in the fiddle it will work on any site.

Comment: So this is what you want? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LY97z/1/). Another [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LY97z/2/)

Comment: yes exactly! BUT, I want to be able to do the same from any place in the browser, so even if i scroll down, the divs appear at the same place, so that I can see them entirely. let's say that I scroll a bit, when I click on the button, I don't want the divs to appear up in the hidden part of my page, but I want them to ENTIRELY appear wherever I am in my page.

Comment: this should normally be done with `position:fixed`, but with the code that I pasted up there, it doesn't seam to work..

Comment: Check this out [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LY97z/4/) if you scroll down it will show where you are. not at the top. It works. Click to make it appear and disappear.

Comment: well actually it works perfectly when I try it on simple test page where I just have my divs, but still when I put it in my main code, it doesn't work, there seams to be so incompatibility or something that is blocking it in my code! any thoughts on that?

Comment: Don't normal do this but if the code isn't tons and messy etc. Post it in a fiddle and I will have a look. There will be something in there "breaking" it.

Answer (score 0):

Right lets have a look here, this is using none of your code and I know this works!

So we set the `divs` that we want to hide to `position: fixed;` then put them out of sight using `left`, `right` and `top`.

From here is as simple as setting some jQuery (or Javascript) `.click` to tell the hidden `divs` to come out. Simple as.

So click anywhere on the screen to bring up the hidden `divs` and click again to hide them. Scroll down and click and they will be on the screen still because we `position: fixed`.

Have a mess around with it to learn how it works etc.

**Note:** *For my one I used CSS `transition` for the animation.*

### HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>Scroll Down and Click</div>
<div>Scroll Down and Click</div>
<span></span>
```

### CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    left: -401px;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s;
    transition: left 2s;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    top: -401px;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transition: top 2s;
    transition: top 2s;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    right: -401px;
    -webkit-transition: right 2s;
    transition: right 2s;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: blue;
}
div:nth-child(5) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: purple;
}
span {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

### jQuery:

```
$("span").click(function () {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
        $("div:nth-child(1)").css("left", "-401px");
        $("div:nth-child(2)").css("top", "-401px");
        $("div:nth-child(3)").css("right", "-401px");
    } else {

        $("div:nth-child(1)").css("left", "0");
        $("div:nth-child(2)").css("top", "0");
        $("div:nth-child(3)").css("right", "0");
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LY97z/5/)

Comment: wow I got it. the problem is with `position:relative` in `#content` . when I removed it, it gave me an ugly result, but at least it gave me a result.. Do you have any idea why? or how it should be done? your code really helps, but I am trying to fix the problem with the least changes possible. thanks anyway :D .. but yea any idea why `position:relative` is affecting it?

Comment: lol well Ruddy I put all my code up there :).. that's at least the relevant parts of my code for my bug.

Comment: like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/wHW4B/) use `z-index` to bring them on top of everything else.

Comment: It is working now.. apparently it was a problem with the fact that I put position:relative for #content, and did not put position:relative for #selected-program.. Thanks for your help Ruddy :)